# Margin before beamercolorbox when aligning more than one

Tags: beamer, themes

The following code:

```
\documentclass{beamer}

% DEFINE COLORS. ---------------------------------------------------------------
\definecolor{bgo}{HTML}{111111}
\definecolor{bgt}{HTML}{555555}
\definecolor{fgo}{HTML}{EEEEEE}


% SET COLORS. ------------------------------------------------------------------
\setbeamercolor{author in head/foot}{fg=fgo, bg=bgo}
\setbeamercolor{title in head/foot}{fg=fgo, bg=bgt}
\setbeamercolor{section in head/foot}{fg=fgo, bg=bgo}


\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{ocp}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframetitle{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}\\
  \hbox{%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}Author
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.45\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframetitle{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.45\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
      \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}Section
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  }%
  \vskip0pt%  \fi%
}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}
\frametitle{Frame Title}
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

Gives:

[image]

Why is there a margin before the hbox? How can I remove it?

---

[Temporary solution]

Instead of using an `hbox`, use a `beamercolorbox` :

```
\defbeamertemplate*{frametitle}{ocp}{%
  \nointerlineskip%
  \leavevmode%
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
    \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframetitle{}
  \end{beamercolorbox}\\
  \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=\paperwidth]{}
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.1\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,left]{author in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{author in head/foot}Author
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.45\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,center]{title in head/foot}%
      \usebeamerfont{title in head/foot}\insertframetitle{}
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
    \begin{beamercolorbox}[wd=.45\paperwidth,ht=2.25ex,dp=1ex,right]{section in head/foot}%
      \usebeamercolor{section in head/foot}Section
    \end{beamercolorbox}%
  \end{beamercolorbox}
  \vskip0pt%  \fi%
}
```

[image]

This solution works and I think it has to do with the fact that the width of the first `beamercolorbox` is the maximum width but it's strange because if I use my first implementation for the footnote, for example, it works perfectly.

Comment: The margin is there because it is the left margin of the frame - the same you see in normal text. `beamercolorbox` is a special case which will cancel the normal text margin if the box is wider than the normal text width.